# Using Drop Link field with SXA Facets Component shows GUID instead of Title

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I am using Lucene search engine.

When using drop link field in SXA facets component, it displays GUID,

I see other posts talking about this issue, and in order to fix it, we should change the below settings to true in `sitecore.buckets.config`

```
<setting name="BucketConfiguration.ResolveFacetValueToFriendlyName" value="**true**"/>
```

But After changing it still facet Component is displaying GUID. Any pointer for this issue would highly appriciated.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the BucketConfiguration.ResolveFacetValueToFriendlyName setting, but could you mention that in your question - and maybe share a screenshot or some extra information?

Comment: Yep, some screenshots might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check this part of the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/extend_search#_Extend_search_to_3

This explains how to use a link type field in the facets. Add a computed field and use that fieldname in the facet:

> Add the following definition to your search configuration file:

```
<field fieldName="referenced"
  type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" 
  referenceField="link"
  contentField="title"/>
```

> where:
>
> fieldName – attribute that defines the index field name where the
>   value will be stored.
>
> referenceField – attribute that defines the field name of the indexed
>   item.
>
> contentField – attribute that defines the field of the referenced item
>   from which the value will be retrieved during the indexing.

Don't forget to rebuild your index after the change.