# Filter (Checklist) component shows ids of facets not values in SXA

Tags: sxa

### Introduction

We are using Sitecore 9 Update 2 with SXA 1.7.1.

We have implemented "Download Center" using OOTB search components from SXA.

We would like to show "Title" value of Checklist field instead of GUIDs in Filter(Checklist) component.

### Question

How we can show value of "Title" field instead of indexed GUIDs in filter (checklist) component?

[image]

### Setup of solution

Custom Template that we have created (inherits Foundation interface template _Searchable + adds new fields):
[image]

We have created hierarchy of tags under Data > Tags (we are refering to these from template as can be seen above):

[image]

This is how it looks like on item itself:

[image]

Setup of Checklist filter  (same is done also for remaining fields):

[image]

**How we should configure this to show Title field instead of GUID?**

This is how the facet is configured (which is referenced in above checklist filter setup):

[image]

This is how the filter looks now:

[image]

### Resolution 1 - Filtering not  working

I have tried to use Tag Treelist instead and created another field.
It solved somehow the issue as I can see topic instead of ID but filtering is not working in this case:

[image]

### Resolution 2 - Facets not displayed

I have also tried to create new indexed fields instead but it is also not working with them (no values can be filtered):

[image]

This is how fields are indexed:

[image]

I have set facets accordingly:

[image]

[image]

I have used name with "_sm" suffix as suggested by Gatogordo so full field name is specified as it is indexed in Solr:

[image]

Seems that the values are coming but they are not rendered:

[image]

Comment: Check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8861/using-drop-link-field-with-sxa-facets-component-shows-guid-instead-of-title/12392#12392  My answer there is correct but not accepted so can't mark it as duplicate..  I could copy it here :)

Comment: I have seen that question and also updated my answer. I have tried it but it is not working. Can you maybe show where the field should be used then?

Comment: Once you created the computed fields, you should check your index and take the exact name of the fields in the index (including suffix) and put that in the config in Sitecore as "fieldname"

Comment: So the field won't be referenced as `topictitle` but `topictags_sm` in facet configuration? This information was missing then from the answer @Gatogordo

Comment: True.. I'll create a new one here with that included.

Comment: Well, you should not add field types suffixes in the facet item `Field Name` field. The type should be automatically resolved by Sitecore logic. Take a look at how it's working e.g.: with Title. Check the search.log and you will see that `_t` suffix is automatically added by search logic. Which mean that the type has been automatically resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it works out of the box with minor config change. Ensure that all of your custom fields which stores tags are using `Tag Treelist` field type. Here are mine custom fields:

[image]

That's the only config change which I did - to be honest, I don't even know if this is required. The field type should be detected correctly anyway:

[image]

I've just used one of the fields in this example and filtering works fine. Numbers next to tags are correct then same with results:

[image]

And here is hot the TopicTags field looks like the inside of the Solr:

[image]

And the facet itself:

[image]

Comment: What's your search querystring look like? Mine still doesn't work with space between the facet words. In browser the url is just like http://xxxxx.local/search#sxatags=Two%20Words . Sitecore 9.2 with SXA 1.9.

Comment: @zhanke did you manage to find the solution with the whitespace in between the facet words for Sitecore 9.2 with SXA 1.9?

Comment: @ReyRahadian it's a bug, you can request a patch from Sitecore Support

Answer (score 1):

You need to check this part of the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/extend_search#_Extend_search_to_3

This explains how to use a link type field in the facets.

**Index config**

Add a computed field and use that fieldname in the facet:

> Add the following definition to your search configuration file:

```
<field fieldName="referenced"
  type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" 
  referenceField="link"
  contentField="title"/>
```

> where:
>
> fieldName – attribute that defines the index field name where the
>   value will be stored.
>
> referenceField – attribute that defines the field name of the indexed
>   item.
>
> contentField – attribute that defines the field of the referenced item
>   from which the value will be retrieved during the indexing.

Don't forget to rebuild your index after the change.

**Sitecore facet config**

Once the fields are added to the index, check the index to get the exact name of the field in the index (including the suffix). Put this name in your facet's fieldname.

That last part can be tricky.. if it doesn't work, check the url that is made for the facets and see if that actually has data.

**Bugs**

Unfortunately there are some bugs with the javascript for checkbox filters. One bug creates a lowercase version of your facet value (and it should keep the casing). Another one is on the active-facet class which is not set with multiple values or when the value has a space. If you contact support, you can get a fix.. (or just ask on Slack)

You might need to avoid spaces ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working @Gatogordo. See Resolution 2 in my answer for further details

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change your field type to "tag tree", Just add this tag
 to fieldReaders tag in your search configuration, then rebuild the indexes, you will find *_sm value in solr will retrieve the name instead of item Guild

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the field to tag treelist, publish and re-index will resolve this. SXA stores tags as the title value, not the ID. Checking the values in SOLR for sxaTags field confirms if the issue is resolved (showing titles) or not (showing id's)