# Computed Index Field for TreeList in SOLR

Tags: solr, indexing, tree-list, computed-field

as treelist values is being indexed in solr as IDs so I needed to create a computed index field for it to read the names, as follows

```
namespace TAMM.SXA.Feature.ServiceDetails.ComputedIndexFields
{
    public class FAQRelatedADGEsField : AbstractComputedIndexField
    {
        public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
        {

            Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

            StringBuilder ADGEsNameList = new StringBuilder();

            if (item == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (item.TemplateName == "FAQ")
            {
                Database currentDatabase = item.Database;
                if (item.Fields["FAQ Related ADGE"].HasValue)
                {
                    var ADGEsIDs = item.Fields["FAQ Related ADGE"].Value.ToString().Split(new[] { '|' },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    foreach (var ADGEID in ADGEsIDs)
                    {
                        ID FAQADGEID = new ID(ADGEID);
                        Item FAQADGEItem = currentDatabase.GetItem(FAQADGEID, item.Language);
                        if (FAQADGEItem != null)
                        {

                            ADGEsNameList.Append(FAQADGEItem.Name.ToString() + ",");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return ADGEsNameList;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to register it as stringCollection as follows

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
      <!-- Configuration sections for indexes -->
      <indexConfigurations>
        <!-- If an index has no configuration specified, it will use the configuration below. The configuration is not merged if the index also has
             configuration, it is either this configuration or the index configuration. -->
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="FAQRelatedADGEsField" returnType="stringCollection">TAMM.SXA.Feature.ServiceDetails.ComputedIndexFields.FAQRelatedADGEsField,TAMM.SXA.Feature.ServiceDetails</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

but when querying Solr I get the field like this

```
"faqrelatedadgesfield_sm":["First Entity,Second Entity,"],
```

the purpose is to use this field in a facet to be displayed as checklist filter

can anyone help to get the computed index right?

Comment: @Gatogordo yes it's SXA enviroment, but the main goal is translating treelist index from list of IDs to list of Names into a new computed field

Comment: Reason I had to be sure it was SXA (althoughh your namespace gave it away) was to lead you to the answer(s) in a recently asked question solving your problem without custom coding ;)

Comment: @Gatogordo This looks promising, thank you, I will try and update you with my result

Comment: @Gatogordo Do I have to change treelist to tagtreelist?, as I can't change that

Comment: Might depend on the solution.. I haven't tried the solution from Dawid yet - mine works for all link fields.

Comment: @Gatogordo so if I'm back to my solution above and instead of getting the value as "faqrelatedadgesfield_sm":["First Entity,Second Entity,"], how can I get it as "faqrelatedadgesfield_sm":["First Entity","Second Entity,"],

Comment: Old, but for anyone passing through. The issue is that you're returning a string, not a collection of strings (list/array) in your computed field. `ADGEsNameList` should be a `List<string>` not a `StringBulilder`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and maybe should) use the options that SXA gives you. The are described in the answers here: [Filter (Checklist) component shows ids of facets not values in SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14149/filter-checklist-component-shows-ids-of-facets-not-values-in-sxa)  (one of them is actually the code you are trying to write but which is already written by the SXA team).

If you do really want to write your own code, return a collection of strings (IEnumerable or List) instead of a single string with comma's.