# SXA Tags are not searchable

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7, I want when the user enters a SXA tag name, all the items tagged by this tag are returned at the search results.

I tried it but no results are returned, I checked the Solr, the tag is indexed :
`sxatags_sm":["Visitor"]`.

I made the `_Taggable` and the `Tag` templates inherits from `_Searchable` template and rebuilt the index, but still it's not searchable.

Comment: Looks like some of the steps you provided are incorrect. You should be using the sxatags field as a facet used by components like Droplist filter. Refer to the SXA documentation site for detailed instructions.

Comment: I think this discussion can help you:https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14149/filter-checklist-component-shows-ids-of-facets-not-values-in-sxa

Comment: @MichaelWest Yes I know it, but I have a requirement that user has to search the items by using its tags as a keyword not by filtering it.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski, I read it, but it's not what I want. I think there is no an OOTB solution for it, I have tried to make a custom one but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to use Search Box to search item by tags. By the default, it is not possible because Search Box is using Aggregated Content (this field in the index will be named `sxacontent`) computed field. This field contains only extracted text content of an item and tags are assigned as an IDs.

You have a few options:

- override `AggregatedContent` computed field (method `ComputeFieldValue()`) so that it will also include tags names into the `sxacontent` index field - in such case Search Box will work as you expect it
- override `ContentPredicate()` method in `Search Service` so that instead of just checking `AggregatedContent` field it will also take a look for tags
- re-design your approach and use **Filter (Checklist)** rendering with tags

I would recommend using the third option. If you would like to take a more advanced approach go with the first option as overriding Search Service is more tricky than simply config update which you have in a first proposition.

Comment: All right,Thank you this really helped me.

Comment: I will go with the first option, but which dll do I have to override ? What is its name ?

Comment: @MohamedYaseenMosa Open `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config` file and look for `<field fieldName="sxacontent" returnType="textCollection" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search">`. Namespace is defned in type attribute.