# How to show the filter values in Chinese in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: content-search, multilingual, search-facet, sxa-search

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 .we have a requirement that the filter values should get displayed in chinese language.

I have created a template with field color and data type multiroot tree list
[image]

I have changed the display names of the color items to chinese and selected those items in my data folder.

[image]

but in the frontend dropdown i am able to see the Item Id's which is splitted into multiple parts

[image]

**Workaround on Gatogordo's suggestion:**

I added the below code in Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config

```
<field fieldName="color_sm"
                    type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" referenceField="Color" contentField="color"/>
```

This is my fruit template:
[image]

This is my color template:
[image]

Facet details

[image]

This is my dropdown filter:
[image]

This is the result i am getting now:

[image]

**2nd round workaround**

Fruit template

[image]

Color template:

[image]

Facet details:

[image]

Colors:

[image]

Config change:

```
 <field fieldName="colortext" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" 
                                   referenceField="color" contentField="Color"/>
```

Current result:

[image]

**After removing the fields from the template i m getting the below result:**

[image]

Solr Data:

[image]

Can anyone please help how can i achieve the chinese data under my dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: To use linked fields in facets, you need to create a computed field (no code, just add config): https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/12392/237

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Drop Link field with SXA Facets Component shows GUID instead of Title](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8861/using-drop-link-field-with-sxa-facets-component-shows-guid-instead-of-title)

Comment: No this didnt work @Gatogordo

Comment: You should explain what you did and what didn't work - that is the way to do it. As long as you are seeing guids (or parts of) you are not using the correct field in the facet.

Comment: @Gatogordo I have update the question with the workarounds please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your configuration as:

```
<field fieldName="colortext" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" referenceField="color" contentField="Color"/>
```

After doing so, don't forget to rebuild the SXA indexes and verify that you now have a field "colortext" which has the values of the colors (not the guids).

Then you change the fieldname in the facet to be "colortext". I've had situations where I had to use the exact index name including the suffix (so like colortext_sm), so if it doesn't work try that...

But step 1 is to make sure you have the values in the index.

Comment: I added colortext field to my color template and changed the color field to colortext in fruit template ,changed the facet fieldname and added the above configuration but i am able to see only 2 colors in my dropdown other colors are not showing

Comment: I have updated my work around please suggest where i am going wrong @Gatogordo

Comment: You don't have to change the name of your field or add other fields.. that's the whole trick. You only add a field to your index, not to Sitecore.

Comment: i removed the added fields from the template and just kept the configuration and the facet name to "colortext" but still i m getting the item ID and for only one item it is showing the color name updated in the last screenshot @Gatogordo

Comment: Did you rebuild the index and verify in solr that the colortext field is correctly filled?

Comment: yes i have rebuilt and that field is also filled with chinese color values not the ID's @Gatogordo

Comment: Then it is weird that you get values that are not in the actual index field..  are you sure the facet is published correctly?  Maybe try with "colortext_sm" in the facet? Sometimes that helps.

Comment: Published everything once and rebuit the indexes it solved .Thanks @Gatogordo