Sitecore Search Scope or token - Multilist field
I have multiple pages based on the "Article" template, and all of them contain a Multilist field named "CustomTags." This field allows the selection of multiple values.
Currently, I am browsing a specific page and using a Search Results component to display related content. I am attempting to create a search scope that filters items based on the template name and the CustomTags field value using the SXA query:
sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|CustomTags;template:{bf9b166a-b6f3-4a9f-9561-a218ed50dbf8}

My goal is to retrieve other pages that share the same CustomTags value as the current page and display them as related pages (including their title and URL). However, the query above is not working as expected.

Did you checked the solr query in the logs to check the values are getting passed as expected?

The CustomTags field stores GUIDs of the selected items. For the sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField query to work. The CustomTags field in the index must be in a format that matches the current item's values.
For example if multilist value is pipe separated values then it will try to match the exact same value in other items also.

This is difficult to answer completely without knowing the details of your fields and what you are exactly expecting but a few things to get you going:

check the executed query in the logs and use that in the solr admin to verify what is exactly wrong with it
if the issue is guids vs actual values, you should know that you can easily create a field that stores the values of linked fields with Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks. More info here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/12392/237
If the logic from the ItemsWithTheSameValueInField is not what you really need (and that could be very well the case, especially with multilist fields as they do need to match exactly and that does not seem to handle your 'related items' requirement)..  you might need to go custom, but the good news is that you can. I have it documented https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html It might not be exactly the same in the current version but should be good enough to get you started if you want/need to go this way.

